# Classical Mech Problems and Exercises (Book/PDF reccomendation)

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm looking for recommendations for sets of problems and exercises to help with exam prep for my classical mechanics course. Our course follows Taylor's book, and so far we have covered through chapter 3 (Kinematics, velocity-dependent forces, momentum and angular momentum). We have yet to cover the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formulations.

We have an exam coming up, and in order to adequately prepare, I'm looking for problems to work that are a significant step up in difficulty from those offered in the Taylor text. My professor makes one (of 2 total) exam questions a decent step up from anything seen on our homework, and the most difficult (3 star) problems in Taylor all fall in the easier range of what is seen on our homework sets. Any recommendations to books or problem sets with difficult exercises are very helpful, thanks!